# Changing a sprite at runtime in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

Is there a way for me to alter the following script to change a specific sprite?

I would like to change a Sprite called `Background1` to another one called `Background2` when the score is at a specific number.

For example to change the Sprite when the score is 25.

```
public class Score : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private static int score = 0;
    private static int highScore = 0;

    public static void AddPoint() 
    {
        score++;

        if (score > highScore)
            highScore = score;
    }

    private void Start() 
    {
        score = 0;
        highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highScore", 0);
    }

    private void OnDestroy() => PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highScore", highScore);
    private void Update()    => guiText.text = "Score: " + score + "\nHigh Score: " + highScore;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For this implementation you have to create sprite array as per your required size.

```
public Sprite[] backgrounds;
```

Manage counter for your background and accessing sprite renderer component, you can change background your game.

```
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = backgrounds[index];
```

I think now you got my point. If you want any more detail related to my then comment it.